# Docker Image Build on Ubuntu: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am running Ubuntu 14 in codeanywhere.com, and I'm getting **"Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?"** error when I try to build the docker image.

Also, when I try to stop docker, I'm getting **"stop: Unknown instance:"**, looks like Docker never got started.

How should I fix this problem?

```
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$ sudo service docker start
docker start/running, process 1392
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$ sudo docker  build .
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace$ sudo service docker stop
stop: Unknown instance:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried installing docker on an ubuntu-14 machine running on codeanywhere.com right now using this [guide](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1), and when the installation process was finished I found this error in `/var/log/upstart/docker.log` -

`time="2018-02-10T03:09:22.148778137-05:00" level=fatal msg="Your Linux kernel version 2.6.32-042stab112.15 is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer."`

Even if upgrading the kernel is somehow possible, I don't think `codeanywhere.com` is the right place to install docker on, as the env itself is probably a docker container. If you're adamant about doing this, perhaps you should contact them and check for the best course of action for your needs.